# Failed to access images using local Parse server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm running Parse server 2.2.18 on localhost, and my database is running on AWS.

My app works fine except that images are not showing up (no such issue using Parse.com). I get the following error when I click the the image link in dashboard.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>A6E654536D1E88D8</RequestId>
<HostId>
+cgzt+zHIZicMLifWDwid/WY/Ekk8DKEOH2ydWtj+lZc3lw7LljeOGzrryCiztYEljC3XIA+fRQ=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: You are using directAccess or not?

Comment: @RanHassid Are you asking about S3_DIRECT? Looks like I'm not using it.

Comment: Can you try to use it and check if you still get an error ?

Comment: I still cannot access photos after setting S3_DIRECT=true.